# how to fix this aggregation issue in mongodb redact

Tags: mongodb, shell, mongodb-query, pipeline, aggregation

i have people dataset in mongodb,  where i want to get all people whom friends has id greater than 1. i tried using $redact aggregation pipeline but it is not working. here is sample data

```
{
"_id" : "5d7a16904d08c0c435e4255b",  
"name" : {
    "first" : "Roberta",
    "last" : "Jackson"
},
"company" : "YURTURE",
"email" : "roberta.jackson@yurture.io",
"age":26,
"registered" : "Sunday, May 5, 2019 2:44 PM",
"latitude" : "36.56389",
"longitude" : "-72.518115",
"friends" : [ 
    {
        "id" : 0,
        "name" : "Vicki Peck"
    }, 
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "name" : "Jeanie Boyd"
    }, 
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "name" : "Terra Curtis"
    }
],
```

}

i tried using aggregation pipeline redact but i am not getting any data in friends list.

```
db.getCollection('test_redact').aggregate([  {    $project:{        
"name" : 1,
      "friends" : 1,
      "greeting" : 1,
      }},
       {
           $redact:{
               $cond: {
                    if: { $gte: [ "$friends.id", 1 ] },                           
                   then: "$$DESCEND",
                   else: "$$PRUNE"
                   }
                   }
           }
])
```

here is sample output i am getting after executing aggregation
    `{
    "_id" : "5d7a16904d08c0c435e4255b",
    "age" : 26,
    "friends" : [],
    "greeting" : "Hello, Roberta! You have 9 unread messages."
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.getCollection("collection").find({"friends.id":{$gte:1}},{"name":1,"friends":1,"greeting":1}).pretty()
```

**To get only those friends which has id greater than 1:**

```
db.getCollection("collection").aggregate([
  {
    $match:{
      "friends.id":{
        $gte:1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project:{
      "name":1,
      "friends":{
        $filter:{
          "input":"$friends",
          "as":"friend",
          "cond":{
            $gte:["$$friend.id",1]
          }
        }
      },
      "greeting":1
    }
  }
]).pretty()
```

**Using $redact:**

```
db.getCollection("collection").aggregate([
  {
    $redact:{
      $cond:[
        {
          $or:[
            {
              $gte:["$id",1]    
            },
            {
              $eq:["$id",undefined]
            }
          ]
        },
        "$$DESCEND",
        "$$PRUNE"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project:{
      "name":1,
      "friends":1,
      "greeting":1
    }
  }
]).pretty()
```

Comment: hi, thanks for reply. using fields we get all friend list including whose id is 0.

Comment: i want to ask one doubt. filtering or matching is necessary before $redact aggregation i have seen many aggregation in first stage they do filtering moving forward they project and apply $redact.

Comment: @shreyanshu The general rule is to minimize the number of documents to be passed into the next aggregation stage. In this example, we filtered out those documents which don't have even a single friend with an id greater than 1. Those documents anyway if were not filtered out would not be useful after redact stage. :)